# Reading over HTTP & (hopefully) automating actions using Java

Tags: java, apache, http, https, yahoo-finance

Is there a way to make get & put calls over HTTP in java ? I also need to automate any user inputs like a button click on the target web-page(any web-page, not just yahoo finance)

**I tried using the apache commons library & couldn't quite crack it:**

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Fin {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://finance.yahoo.com");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            httpget.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

}
```

I keep getting 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused', though i can see it in the browser.

Comment: You may want to try turning the log level down to DEBUG or TRACE as I think the Apache HTTP library generally provides good information about what it is doing at those levels... maybe something will become apparent.

Comment: @cjstehno : I had forgotten to add my proxy,quite sorry about that...my bad...

Now can someone answer the second part of my question on how to automate any user inputs like a button click on the target web-page?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing functional testing... have you looked into libraries like Geb or Selenium rather than trying to write your own framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to automate browser-based interactions, you could go further and use Watij, which runs a browser via the JVM and is driven via a browser-based API (I.e. you identify the button you want to press and it will actually *do* this)

Otherwise a library like the one you've identified will normally work. You have to watch out for client-side JavaScript interactions driving the requests, and configure proxies etc (I suspect this is your problem in the above)

Comment: Thank you Brian, cjstehno, I had a look at the frameworks & selenium, Imacros & wattij look promising